# Web to lead assignment rules

Tags: assignment-rules

I  have a lead record which was created from web and assigned with proper queue based on its country in address. Incase same record is updated by its country field  in web, record is updating correctly. but queue is not changing  based on its new country value .
     So we are selecting Assignment rule check box manually every time on those records who  are get updated in web. please guide me why manually check box selection is only assigning queues to web to lead records?

Answer (score 1):

Lead assignment rules do not happen automatically when a Lead is inserted/updated (via Apex DML or API call)

So, since your Leads are coming from some Web Server, each API call that inserts or updates Leads needs to set the `AssignmentRuleHeader`

From the [Soap Doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_header_assignmentruleheader.htm):

> AssignmentRuleHeader
>
> The AssignmentRuleHeader must be specified in the
>   create() or update() call of a Case or Lead for the specified
>   assignment rule to be applied, and it must be specified in the
>   update() call of an Account for the territory assignment rules to be
>   applied.

From the [REST doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/headers_autoassign.htm)

> Assignment Rule Header
>
> The Assignment Rule header is a request header
>   applied when creating or updating Cases or Leads. If enabled, the
>   active assignment rules are used. If disabled, the active assignment
>   rules are not applied. If a valid AssignmentRule ID is provided, the
>   AssignmentRule is applied. If the header is not provided with a
>   request, REST API defaults to using the active assignment rules.